# NHibernate Query w/ criteria against collection items

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following configuration in the database.

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCj04.png)

[image]

I want to be able to query all the Individuals where they are either an employee or vendor.  Of the examples I've seen I can't get any of them to work.  The code doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't bring back any records.

Here are the DTO's

```
public class Individual
{
    public virtual int Sid { get; set;}
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    private bool _inactive;

    public virtual int Sid { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Individual> Individuals { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active
    {
        get { return !_inactive; }
        set { _inactive = value; }
    }
    public virtual bool IsVendor { get; set; }
}

public class IndividualCompany
{
    public virtual Individual Individual { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        IndividualCompany key = obj as IndividualCompany;
        if (key == null)
            return false;

        if (Individual.Sid == key.Individual.Sid && Company.Sid == key.Company.Sid)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;

        hash = 7 * hash * Individual.Sid.GetHashCode();
        hash = 7 * hash * Company.Sid.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

I have another function that uses these 3 tables and all my Individuals and the collection of Companies gets populated just fine so I know the mapping is working.  I just don't know how to add criteria on the child record.

```
string sql = "from Individual i" +
        " inner join fetch i.Companies";
return _session.CreateQuery(sql).List<Individual>();
```

Here's the query I'd like it to produce.

```
select i.*
  from individual i inner join individual_company_assoc ica
    on i.individual_sid = ica.individual_sid
 inner join company c
    on ica.company_sid = c.company_sid
 where c.is_vendor = 0
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
public IList<Individual> Get(bool vendorsOnly)
{
    try
    {
        return _session.CreateCriteria<Individual>()
            .CreateAlias("Company", "c")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.IsVendor", vendorsOnly))
            .List<Individual>();
    }
    catch (NHibernate.HibernateException)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I'm not using FluentNHibernate.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An nHibernate query will not automatically join with other tables, even if you reference columns of a joining table in the query.

You must explicitly state that the query should join with the Company table.

Here's an example which will work. It uses the `QueryOver` syntax, which is a type-safe wrapper around the Criteria API.

```
return _session
           .QueryOver<Individual>()
           .JoinQueryOver<Company>(i => i.Companies>())
           .Where(c => c.IsVendor == vendorsOnly)
           .TransformUsing(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
           .List();
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew!  Your solution worked flawlessly!  +1